# Receive input in an IF statement in PL/SQL?

Tags: if-statement, plsql

Hey all I am wondering if it's possible to recieve a second input if an `if` statement is trigured in PL/SQL?  Here is the code I have now:

```
set serveroutput on
accept v_enter prompt "Enter employees salary: "
declare 
  v_emppay number(10,0):='&v_enter';
  v_numemps number (3,0):='&v_enter2';
  v_jobsec varchar2(40);
  v_jobname emp.job%type;
begin
  select job into v_jobname
  from emp
  where ename = 'ADAMS';

  if v_emppay > 2000 and v_jobname = 'PRESIDENT' then
     v_jobsec := 'Safe';
     elsif
      v_emppay > 2000 and v_jobname <> 'MANAGER' then
      v_jobsec := 'Not Safe';
      elsif
        v_emppay > 2000 and v_jobname = 'MANAGER' then
          accept v_enter2 prompt "How many underlings? "
          if v_numemps < 3 then
            v_jobsec := 'Not Safe'
          else
            v_jobsec := 'Safe'
          end if   
        elsif 
        v_emppay > 1000 and v_jobname <> 'MANAGER' then
        v_jobsec := 'Safe';
        else
          v_jobsec := 'Safe';
  end if;

  dbms_output.put_line ('You are '||v_jobsec);
end;
```

As of right now I get asked to insert(without the prompt) a value regardless if the person is a manager or not, and if he is a manager then the program errors out.  This is my second day using PL/SQL so I'm sure some of my syntax is wrong, but as of right now I cant see where.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: PL/SQL and SQL*Plus are not good at this type of interaction.  You can do this, but you'll need to split the logic into multiple blocks, and conditionally run a script that will prompt for the extra input.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11236186/409172) for an example.

Answer (score -1):

As I understood you need to ask if someone is a manager and then if he is just to set output message that he is? Am I correct? So you need just one more IF and exception....
This is how would I do it.... simple

```
set serveroutput on
accept v_enter prompt "Enter employees salary: "
declare 
  v_emppay number(10,0):='&v_enter';
  v_numemps number (3,0):='&v_enter2';
  v_jobsec varchar2(40);
  v_jobname emp.job%type;
  e_exit exception;
begin
  select job into v_jobname
  from emp
  where ename = 'ADAMS';

  if v_jobname = 'MANAGER' then
     raise e_exit;
  end if;

  if v_emppay > 2000 and v_jobname = 'PRESIDENT' then
     v_jobsec := 'Safe';
     elsif
      v_emppay > 2000 and v_jobname <> 'MANAGER' then
      v_jobsec := 'Not Safe';
      elsif
        v_emppay > 2000 and v_jobname = 'MANAGER' then
          accept v_enter2 prompt "How many underlings? "
          if v_numemps < 3 then
            v_jobsec := 'Not Safe'
          else
            v_jobsec := 'Safe'
          end if   
        elsif 
        v_emppay > 1000 and v_jobname <> 'MANAGER' then
        v_jobsec := 'Safe';
        else
          v_jobsec := 'Safe';
  end if;

  dbms_output.put_line ('You are '||v_jobsec);
  exception
     when e_exit then
       dbms_output.put_line ('You are manager');
end;
```

Comment: SQL*Plus and PL/SQL don't mix like this - `ERROR at line 23:`.

Comment: i didn't wrote ; sign behind not safe , safe