# Run an SQL script only if a selection over a table before it gives a result. If it doesn't give a result the SQL script should not run

Tags: sql, oracle, command

I would like an SQL script to run only if a SQL command selection over a table give a result.

If it doesn't give a result the SQL script should not run.

Will this be possible to do?

Comment: ya you can do this in many ways!how u want to do this using cursor or trigger simple if?

Comment: Are you trying to conditionally run a script in SQL*Plus?  If so, take a look at this method: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11236186/409172

Answer (score 0):

I might help:

```
IF ( select count(1) from  ( _your selection_ ) a ) > 0 THEN
_RUN your script_;
END IF
```

Answer (score 0):

this is one way:

```
DECLARE
type t1
IS
  TABLE OF hr.employees.first_name%type;
  t11 t1;
BEGIN
  SELECT e.first_name bulk collect
  INTO t11
  FROM hr.employees e
  WHERE E.EMPLOYEE_ID=999;
  IF(t11.count!      =0) THEN
    FOR i           IN 1..t11.count/*here you can write your own query */
    LOOP
      dbms_output.put_line(t11(i));
    END LOOP;
  ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line('oh..ho..no rows selected' );
  END IF;
END;
/
```

any clarification plz let me know..